# Redirecting non-existing paths to a specific page

Tags: javascript, html, web

I am trying to redirect users who browse paths that doesn't exist to another page I set.
Example:
site.com/dhdhshs will redirect users to a specitic page because the path is not available.
How can I do this, also what kind of file should I create or edit on the webserver?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

404 redirects must be handled at the server-side. Following are the steps to do it.

1. Create a `.htaccess` file.
2. Add `ErrorDocument 404 http://www.yourdomain.com/404.html` to it.
3. Place it in the root directory of your project.

Answer (score -3):

Inside 404 page:

```
window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com";
```

Comment: URI is stored in the `href` property of `window.location` object. So it is `window.location.href` (I am not the downvoter)

Comment: windows.location = 'http://www.example.com' is a synonym of location.href =